# in-text citation call-out style

Tags: citing, ieeetran

How can change the intext reference style from `[1][2][3]` to `[1-3]`. Another thing I would like to do is converting from `[1][2][3][12]` to `[1-3,12]`. I am using `\cite{}` command for the in-text citation call-outs. Also, I employ the IEEE transactions bibliography style, `IEEEtran`. Let say I have 3 references as follow;

```
@article{maskery2017investigation,
  title={An investigation into reinforced and functionally graded lattice structures},
  author={Maskery, Ian and Hussey, Alexandra and Panesar, Ajit and Aremu, Adedeji and Tuck, Christopher and Ashcroft, Ian and Hague, Richard},
  journal={Journal of Cellular Plastics},
  volume={53},
  number={2},
  pages={151--165},
  year={2017},
  publisher={SAGE Publications Sage UK: London, England}
}
@article{Yu2019Investigation,
  title={Investigation of functionally graded TPMS structures fabricated by additive manufacturing},
  author={Yu, Shixiang and Sun, Jinxing and Bai, Jiaming},
  journal={Materials \& Design},
  volume={182},
  pages={108021},
  year={2019},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{dara2022numerical,
  title={Numerical and experimental investigations of novel nature inspired open lattice cellular structures for enhanced stiffness and specific energy absorption},
  author={Dara, Ashok and Bahubalendruni, MV A Raju and Mertens, A Johnney and Balamurali, Gunji},
  journal={Materials Today Communications},
  volume={31},
  pages={103286},
  year={2022},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

and cite them as

```
\cite{maskery2017investigation}\cite{Yu2019Investigation}\cite{dara2022numerical}
```

The results become `[2][3][4]`

Comment: You need to start by providing a full but minimal example others can copy and test. Currently we have to guess too much in order to provide a suggestion

Comment: Thank you for your warning. I have just added some references.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you employ the `cite` citation management style and issue a single `\cite` directive with 3 comma-separated arguments instead of issuing 3 separate `\cite` directives with a single argument each.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@article{maskery2017investigation,
  title={An investigation into reinforced and functionally graded lattice structures},
  author={Maskery, Ian and Hussey, Alexandra and Panesar, Ajit and Aremu, Adedeji and Tuck, Christopher and Ashcroft, Ian and Hague, Richard},
  journal={Journal of Cellular Plastics},
  volume={53},
  number={2},
  pages={151--165},
  year={2017},
  publisher={SAGE Publications Sage UK: London, England}
}
@article{Yu2019Investigation,
  title={Investigation of functionally graded TPMS structures fabricated by additive manufacturing},
  author={Yu, Shixiang and Sun, Jinxing and Bai, Jiaming},
  journal={Materials \& Design},
  volume={182},
  pages={108021},
  year={2019},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{dara2022numerical,
  title={Numerical and experimental investigations of novel nature inspired open lattice cellular structures for enhanced stiffness and specific energy absorption},
  author={Dara, Ashok and Bahubalendruni, MV A Raju and Mertens, A Johnney and Balamurali, Gunji},
  journal={Materials Today Communications},
  volume={31},
  pages={103286},
  year={2022},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\cite{maskery2017investigation, Yu2019Investigation, dara2022numerical} vs.\ 
\cite{maskery2017investigation}\cite{Yu2019Investigation}\cite{dara2022numerical}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Mico. Putting a comma into a \cite command would slightly solve may problem. Have a nice day :).